# What are the dot in variables in "Non-debugging symbols:" in gdb

Tags: gcc, gdb, clang

When gdb the `bash` executable (compiled with -g), and use `info variables` to inspect the variables.

I got something like this. There are dots in the symbols. Could anybody help explain what this notiation means?

```
Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000100105380  read_alias_file.aliasfile
0x000000010010a320  set_pipestatus_from_exit.v
0x000000010010a458  set_maxchild.lmaxchild
0x000000010010a45c  waitchld.wcontinued
0x000000010010bec4  set_restricted_shell.save_restricted
0x000000010010bed0  internal_getopt.errstr
0x000000010010bedc  rangecmp.s1
0x000000010010bede  rangecmp.s2
0x000000010010bee0  rangecmp_wc.s1
```

For example, I see both `read_alias_file` and `aliasfile`. But I don't know what `read_alias_file.aliasfile` means.

```
$ ack read_alias_file
lib/intl/localealias.c
145:static size_t read_alias_file PARAMS ((const char *fname, int fname_len))
205:        added = read_alias_file (start, locale_alias_path - start);
220:read_alias_file (fname, fname_len)
$ ack aliasfile
lib/intl/localealias.c
227:  static const char aliasfile[] = "/locale.alias";
229:  full_fname = (char *) alloca (fname_len + sizeof aliasfile);
232:       aliasfile, sizeof aliasfile);
235:  memcpy (&full_fname[fname_len], aliasfile, sizeof aliasfile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know what read_alias_file.aliasfile means.

It's a global variable `aliasfile`, that is only visible inside `read_alias_file` function.

Since you can have same-named variables in multiple files and functions:

```
// foo.c
static int foo = 42;

// bar.c
int fn1() { static int foo = 43; ... }
int fn2() { static int foo = 44; ... }
```

and these variables must have storage throughout the entire program, the compiler has to somehow uniquify them all so the linker doesn't merge them into a single variable.

Appending a random number, or a hash of file / function name, or the file and function names are common strategies.

Using file / function name (as your compiler apparently does) makes it easier to tell which `foo` came from where. You shouldn't depend on this though -- it's completely up to the compiler (so long as resulting names are sufficiently unique at link time).

Comment: Thanks. BTW, how to add a watchpoint on these static local variables?

Comment: @user1424739 You can watch them once you know their address. E.g. `watch *(int*)0x100105380` should work.